# How to present big_int?

Tags: ocaml, bignum

I am working with `big_int` type. I looked in the OCaml's library `Pervasives`.

For example: in `Int32`

```
let t = 5l
Printf.printf "%ld" t
```

How can I define `t` and which `%?d` if I want to declare it is an `big_int`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Below is a toplevel session. The `#load` directive would become a command-line link option if you used the compiler:

```
# #load "nums.cma" ;;
# let t = Big_int.big_int_of_int 5 ;;
val t : Big_int.big_int = <abstr>
# Printf.printf "%s" (Big_int.string_of_big_int t) ;;
5- : unit = ()
```

For numbers that do not fit in a native `int`, use `Big_int.big_int_of_string`. Example: `Big_int.big_int_of_string "99999999999999999999999"`.

The complete list of functions is [here](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Big_int.html).

Finally, the `Big_int` module is quite old and clumsy. The interface dates back to caml-light, in which the module system was rudimentary. This is the reason why each function name redundantly repeats "big_int...". If you are choosing a big integer library now, I would recommend [Zarith](http://forge.ocamlcore.org/projects/zarith), which is modern and efficient. The drawback of Zarith is that it is a separate download (for now).

Comment: Sorry for the newb question, but how do you do a command-line link for compiling?

Comment: @DrXorile This is a new question and you could have had the answer in 5 minutes if you had asked it as a new question that everyone could see. `ocamlc nums.cma t.ml` or `ocamlopt nums.cmxa t.ml`.

Answer (score 6):

There are several modern "big numbers" libraries for OCaml, all interfaces about GNU MP:

1. My own, mlgmp, which ships with many Linux distributions as libgmp-ocaml.
2. mlgmpidl from Bertrand Jeannet (BEWARE: both mlgmp and mlgmpidl declare themselves to ocamlfind as the Gmp package, thus weird conflicts).
3. ZArith

ZArith is better for two reasons:

1. It tries as much as possible to perform computations on machine integers before allocating GNU MP objects.
2. It allocates GNU MP objects inside the OCaml heap, as opposed to the normal allocation scheme through `malloc()`, which is not very suited to functional programming.